# How to Make a function that works same as explode and implode function

Tags: php

How would I implement a function that works same as the explode and implode functions in PHP?

Comment: `function myExplode($delimiter, $string, $limit = PHP_INT_MAX) { return explode($delimiter, $string, $limit); }`

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? what have you tried so far?

Comment: If you really want to do this manually, take a look at strpos() and substr(). You should be able to accomplish it with just those two functions and some iteration.

Comment: Please add more details

Answer (score 2):

Lets first see in simple terms what does explode do: (from php.net)

> Returns an array of strings, each of which is a substring of string formed by splitting it on boundaries formed by the string delimiter.

which means

```
explode(' ', '1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8'); // will return the array of strings
// array(
//   0 => '1',
//   1 => '2',
//   2 => '3',
//   3 => '4',
//   4 => '5',
//   5 => '6',
//   6 => '7',
//   7 => '8'
// )
```

In above example the delimiter is whitespace and the string is 1...8

Similarly lets break this out in pseudo code:

1. Function takes 2 parameters, delimiter and string
2. create an empty array
3. Find the length of the string
4. Find the first position of the delimiter in the string
5. take the sub-string from the string till the first position of delimiter
6. store the sub-string in an array
7. Repeat the step 3-6 until the string length is zero.
8. Return the array

```
function letsExplode(String $delimiter, String $string): array  
{  
  $arr = [];  
  while(strlen($string) > 0)  
  {  
    $pos = strpos($string, $delimiter);  
    if($pos)  
    {  
      $arr[] = trim(substr($string, 0, $pos));  
      $string = ltrim(substr($string, $pos), $delimiter);  
    } else {  
      $arr[] = trim($string);  
      $string = '';  
    }  
  }  
  return $arr;  
}

letsExplode(' ', '1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8'); or letsExplode(',', '1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8');
// array(
//   0 => '1',
//   1 => '2',
//   2 => '3',
//   3 => '4',
//   4 => '5',
//   5 => '6',
//   6 => '7',
//   7 => ' 8'
// )
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?
function my_implode($array, $delimiter){    
    end($array); //Set the internal pointer of an array to its last element
    $end = key($array); // Fetch a key from the array
    $final_string = "";
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        $final_string .= $value; // adds to the string.
        if($key != $end) $final_string .= $delimiter; //If not end of array adds the delimiter to the string
    }

    return $final_string;
}

function my_explode($string, $delimiter){    
    $array = preg_split("/".$delimiter."/", $string);
    return $array;
}

// test explode/implode:

$string = "this is string djhf sjs jkdfh skjfjdsf hkdsjfh kjsd fhks";
$delimiter = " ";
$array = my_explode($string, $delimiter);

echo "<br>Test Explode, <br><b>String:</b> ".$string."<br><br>";
echo "<b>Result:</b><br>";
echo "<pre>";
print_r($array);
echo "</pre>";

echo "<br><br><br>";

echo "<br>Test Implode:<br><br>";
$string_final = my_implode($array, " ") ;
echo "Result:<br>". $string_final;
echo "<br><br><br>";
if ($string == $string_final) {

    echo "<b>Test Successful.</b> <br> <br>Original String: <br>".$string. "<br>Final String:<br>". $string_final;
    echo "<b><br>String are identical</b>";
} else {
    Echo "<b>Test Failed!</b> <br><br>Original String:<br>".$string. "<br>Final String:<br>". $string_final;
}
```